# Can't Remap my graphics tablet buttons

Tags: xorg, gui, 22.04, wacom, gnome-settings-daemon

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 freshly installed with secure boot Enabled and NVIDIA Proprietary drivers, So my system is on X11. My Graphics tablet is HUION H640p which is surprisingly is working by default, but the stylus isn't.

I'm unable to map the buttons on my tablet using `Assaign keystroke` in the GUI provided by the settings due to a GUI Bug in which I can't select using the mouse or keyboard.

[image: Screenshot]

What I know is that this is a Gnome 42 Bug, which I had it also on Fedora 36 and had the same exact issue

Is there a way or a workaround to this issue, I know about `xsetwacom` but I don't know how to make it run at startup and automatically detects if the tablet was detached from USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: the issue was fixed on the last update of Ubuntu 22.04 on 9th on June 2022, Now I was able to assign my tablet buttons from the settings.